# The method add(String) is undefined for the type String

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<String> indirizzi = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    String ind = in.nextLine();
    indirizzi.get(i).add(ind);
}
```

> The method `add(String)` is undefined for the type `String`.

This program gives me the above error.

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) returns a `String` in this case and then you call `add()` on the `String` returned by `get()`. The `String` class does not have an `add()` method, hence the undefined for type `String` error. I believe you simply wanted:

```
indirizzi.add(ind);
```

Which will add the user input to the `List`.

If you want to add at a specific index then use the [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) method:

```
indirizzi.set(i, ind);
```

Which will set `ind` to the `i`'th index of `indirizzi`

Comment: yeah but I wanted to add the string in that i position of the arraylist

Comment: @user10610048 `add()` adds the element to the end of the list so if the `List` is empty, then it will already be setting the elements to the `ith` position. If not then check my edit about the `set()` method